# Typo3 Version 11.2.0 Backend and frontend not reachable by clicking 'Switch to...'-Buttons inside the Installtool

Tags: php, typo3

I got an Page not found- Error after a fresh install of Typo3 Version 11.2.0 on a PHP-Version 7.4.

I renamed '.htaccess' and Typo3 V11.2.0 asked me to build a new one. I got a white site .

I set a hard link to 'index.php' via Terminal! (Soft linking is only allowed to directories, not to files) then I added the source-path segment in

```
call_user_func(function () {
        $classLoader = require __DIR__.
```

in front of the ''/vendor/....." in line 23.

```
// Set up the application for the frontend
call_user_func(function () {
    $classLoader = require __DIR__.'/typo3_src/vendor/autoload.php';
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::run(0, \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\SystemEnvironmentBuilder::REQUESTTYPE_FE);
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::init($classLoader)->get(\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Http\Application::class)->run();
});
```

I reached my (Sub-)Domain when I entered the URL directly in my browsers address line like: `https.//www.myDomain.TLD/Subdomain/`
(without index.php !) the Starting Page was shown.
Impossible to reach this by the 'Switch to frontend'-Button.
Unlike the behavior of the 'Switch to backend'-Button.
The Login appeared and a very short time later this message

```
'Page Not Found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason:
 The requested page does not exist '
```

was shown. I guess that means 'index.php' works as it looks like. But it can not reach the Frontend via index.php.

In the Environment Directory Status Test there appears this:
`' / is not a directory Directory / should be a directory, but is of type link'.`

(that was no problem in former Installations...and couldn't be fixed by the Typo3 Installation Instance )

Some procedure does not find parts of site configuration. What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

Revert everything you have done except the .htaccess part. This is essential on your TYPO3 installation. the reason why you got the error:

> Page Not Found The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason:
> The requested page does not exist

is because you are missing your **Site Configuration**. On your left sidebar, you have a module with the name **Sites**. Before you go in there, you need to create at least one page and define it as root. (Global icon before the page name). To define a page as **root** you need to edit the page, click on the **Behaviour** tab and enable the "Use as Root Page". Now TYPO3 knows which is the entry point.

[image: Root Page]

Now you have enabled the Sites. Go to your Site modules and there you should be able to find the root page you have defined. Follow the instructions from there and you should be able to have your FrontEnd visible.

Hope it helped,

Best regards

Comment: Thank you, I did like you said: I made a fresh installation again.
But after that it was impossible to enter neither the Backend nor the Frontend, that means, that i don't see the left Sidebar there only appears

`Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

(May be my .user.ini dosn't allow the use of the typo3 error documents) 

An older Typo3 Installation (Version 10.4.17) runs without any errors a the same place. 
@Aristeidis Karavas

Comment: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource. means that your htaccess doesnt allow the path there. Try to delete the htaccess if you didnt. TYPO3 11 has introduced the Backend routing, meaning that the htaccess has been change as well. (Minimal). That means that the TYPO3 10 htaccess wont work with TYPO3 11. (In case you copied it)

Comment: I changed `.htaccess` (deleted it and Typo built a new one.)
The Simple Example Page appears, but neither Backend nor Frontend are reachable clicking the Buttons from inside Install Tool.
Site is reachable if I invoke it via blank URL (without ìndex.php`) but typ3/index.php does not work. typo3/install.php nevertheless works...... @Aristeidis Karavas

Comment: typo3/index.php wont work because it needs a parameter as well. Like  typo3/index.php?pid=1 or somethinhg like that.When you click got to Backend or Frontend in install tool, what does the url look like?

Comment: It looks like this :
(frontend) `https://www.MyDomain.ltd/MySiteName/index.php`
(backend) `https://www.MyDomain.ltd/MySiteName/typo3/index.php` (login appears) 
after entering the login data this URL appears:
`https://www.MyDomain.ltd/MySiteName/typo3/login?loginProvider=1433416747`
and the well-known message is shown:
`
Page Not Found
The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No site configuration found.
`
I tried to load some preconfigured Site, but I couldn't any downloaded data and no sites inside typo3conf..

Comment: I cut the followship for a moment and restored it ... but your are in again. Right?

Comment: I succeeded in a fresh installation of Typo3 V11.2.0 using docker and composer in a Linux environment at home. But on servers of my provider? 
Now I would like to upgrade an existing site running Typo3 v10.4.17without getting rid of the existing content. 
Maybe that isn't just yet possible.
by the way: first I got a nginx - Error caused by an Apache2 port conflict.